# .NET Enum type with multiple definitions

Tags: .net, reflection, enums

Imagine this enumerate:

```
public enum eMyEnum
{
    cValue1 = 0,
    cValue2 = 1,
    cValue2_too = 1,
    cValue3 = 5
}
```

Is there a way to iterate over all the values (not the labels)?  If I try

```
var values = typeof(eMyEnum).GetEnumValues();
```

I end up with `{cValue1,cValue2,cValue2,cValue3}`, while I'm looking for a way to retrieve `{cValue1,cValue2,cValue3}`.  Note: I intentionally left a gap between 1 and 5.

Comment: Are cValue2 and cValue2_too supposed to be the same?  If so, then you're (ab)using enums for something they're not designed for.  Your issue is probably related to some cast from int to the enum (which is totally valid) under the hood.

Comment: @JohnL: from msdn: "You can assign any values to the elements in the enumerator list of an enumeration type" (cfr. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx)

Comment: Right, but AFAIK that's so you can cast them back and forth between ints and have the values be meaningful.  I don't see anything on that article that suggests that having duplicate values would make sense - why do you need this, just out of interest?

Comment: @JohnL: code-compatibility: `enum { a=1, b, c }` became `enum { A=1, a=1, B=2, b=2, C=2, c=2}` so to speak.  All existing code still builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the VB.NET Syntax if anybody is interested:

```
[Enum].GetValues(GetType(eMyEnum)).Cast(of eMyEnum).Distinct
```

or

```
GetType(eMyEnum).GetEnumValues().Cast(of eMyEnum).Distinct
```

so this should be the C# version (cannot test):

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(eMyEnum)).Cast<eMyEnum>().Distinct
```

or

```
typeof(eMyEnum).GetEnumValues().Cast<eMyEnum>().Distinct
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var values = typeof(eMyEnum).GetEnumValues().Select(v => (int)v).Distinct();
```

Comment: after posting my reply I noticed yours and wow I took 12 minutes to make sure my expression was doing the right thing!

Answer (score 0):

Linq could come to rescue for this:

```
IEnumerable<eMyEnum> values = typeof(eMyEnum).GetEnumValues()
                               .Cast<int>().Distinct().Cast<eMyEnum>();
```

Note that this will get you only cValue2 and not cValue2_too i think.